# What kind of persistent store does NSPersistentContainer create by default?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

When I create container on my own by this code what kind of persistent store creates in application support folder?

```
private lazy var storeContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: self.modelName)
    container.persistentStoreDescriptions = [self.storeDescription]
    container.loadPersistentStores { (storeDescription, error) in
        if let error = error {
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(error)")
        }
    }
    return container
}()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, on iOS it creates a persistent store with `NSSQLiteStoreType` and automatic lightweight migration enabled.

Reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/WhatNewCoreData2016/ReleaseNotes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40017342-CH1-DontLinkElementID_3

Comment: Thank you  but if you don't mind, please can you explain why default store is sqlitetype? Or maybe you could send reference to official document? because I did not find actual mention about default kind of persistent store (

Comment: SQLLite is probably the best choice for the Core Data store on iOS, It's backed by SQLlite so is better able to handle memory and yet maintain fast searching. The Binary and InMemory types are rarely used for large stores as they can be memory intensive. I've added the reference to my answer.

Comment: Great I found mention about sqlite through your reference! I got why it appropriate choice) thank you!